# -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class

Tags: ios, swift, nskeyedunarchiver

I have an error I don't understand after I updated my app. I have an app already in the app store. I have some app specific data archived and stored in a file inside application support directory. I was reading and storing the data every time when the app is launched and sent to background. Everything was fine so far. Now I released an update to the app. After the update when I launch the app and try to unarchive the data it crashes with below exception.

```
-[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: 
cannot decode object of class (ProjectName.ProjectFile) for key (root);
the class may be defined in source code or a library that is not linked.
```

If I delete the app and install the app again everything works fine.

Both my original app and update are written in Swift.  I haven't changed the file name also from version 1 to 2. Does any one know what is happening ?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that reinstalling helps. For someone like me who accidentally changed project name and changed back with this problem, reinstallation is the solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the reason for the above.

Basically I changed the project target name from version 1 to version 2. So it was trying to decode `ProjectName2.ProjectFile` instead of `ProjectName.ProjectFile`.

The possible way to avoid is `@objc(PFUserUtils)` for the class when you start the first version. If you change the target name like me, use `NSKeyedUnarchiver.setClass(className forClassName:name)` method to set the class name to old one.

Comment: Why is your file name tied up with "version number"?

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question, this just saved me a lot of headache!

Comment: Appreciate for the answer, really save my life.